# How to retrieve the activity requested by an Intent

Tags: android, class, android-intent, instanceof

Say I have an Intent like this:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
```

I then want a method that will return true for the following:

```
 boolean found = intent.getSomeMethodToRetrieveActivity() instanceof MyActivity;
```

Basically is there any way to find out what Activity the intent resolves to?

any ideas?

*EDIT*

Perusing the [src](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/Instrumentation.java) I can see I can get the class name like this:

```
 intent.getComponent().getClassName()
```

which will return "`com.my.package.MyActivity`" which is close but I'd like to use `instanceof`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I just ended up using `equals()` like in my question with:

```
 intent.getComponent().getClassName()
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using Java's reflection mechanism, concretely `Class.newInstance()` or `Class.isInstance()` methods?